# Wordpress theme with front page and index at the same time?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

When using wordpress' `front-page.php` file on a theme, supposing my site is hosted at http://example.com/, the initial page (`GET /`) would retrieve its contents. Doing that, where do I link back to the `index.php` that lists all latest posts from all categories?

I expected that `GET /posts` or something like that would take me to `index.php`, but it doesn't :(

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

In your WP admin panel, under Settings -> Read, you can specify "home page" and "posts page" (by picking them from a dropdown of the pages on your site).  Whatever you specify as "home page" will take the `front-page.php` template (if it exists, otherwise it will revert to the default `page.php` template), and whatever you specify as the 'posts' page will be considered the 'posts feed' you would normally expect on the homepage and will use the `index.php` template if no `home.php` template exists.

The template hierarchy is flexible enough you can manage this stuff basically in whatever way you want - see the codex for details http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: I tryed that and it didn't work, but thanks! :)
Read my answer below to see what really worked...

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

The thing is not just about the `front-page.php` thing, I had to create a page with a slug called `home`, create a file called `page-home.php`, make the same configuration as Ennui pointed out, and adjust my `page-home.php` to query for the lastest posts, otherwise it would just loop through the page as it was a post.

(WeirdPress...)